# How to combine multiple rows into 1?

Tags: sql, ssms

How to combine multiple rows into 1? 1 row contains default information about an item, a second row contains overridden item information. I need all overridden information but if overridden information is NULL then the default information is required.

Table1 :

| itemxa_intid | item_intdid | prepTech_intid | buyer_intid | srv_Name | prd_Name | default_itemxa_intid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 724156 | 15799 | 32 | NULL | Default Name 1 | Default Name 2 | 724156 |
| 724157 | 15799 | NULL | 12 | NULL | Overridden Name | 724156 |
| 724158 | 15799 | 16 | NULL | Overridden Name | NULL | 724156 |

```
SELECT *
FROM
Table1
WHERE itemxa_intid = 724158 --I know this information from a separate query
```

From that query I find the `default_itemxa_intid` = 724156 and any overridden information.

| itemxa_intid | item_intdid | prepTech_intid | buyer_intid | srv_Name | prd_Name | default_itemxa_intid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 724158 | 15799 | 16 | NULL | Overridden Name | NULL | 724156 |

Another query :

```
SELECT *
FROM
Table1
WHERE itemxa_intid = PreviousQuery.default_itemxa_intid
```

| itemxa_intid | item_intdid | prepTech_intid | buyer_intid | srv_Name | prd_Name | default_itemxa_intid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 724156 | 15799 | 32 | NULL | Default Name 1 | Default Name 2 | 724156 |

This row contains all default values to be used where first query returned NULL values. I need 1 row that contains the two rows combined into 1 row.

| itemxa_intid | item_intdid | prepTech_intid | buyer_intid | srv_Name | prd_Name | default_itemxa_intid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 724158 | 15799 | 16 | NULL | Overridden Name | Default Name 2 | 724156 |

Comment:  Please consider not posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of code or data.

Comment: Well, I don't know why the "desired output" only contains one single row. If your goal is to fill in default values from a designated row full of default values (#724156) into all other rows, then two rows should be left, not one?!

Comment: The desired output is a combination of the default info row and any info that should override the default. This data is a recipe db. So the default row is the ingredient "water" imagine that I use water in multiple recipes. I might want the name water as the general name but in a recipe for hot crust pastry I might want to call it "boiling water". There are many other values that could be a default value for an ingredient but could change depending on how they are used. This is why I want to retrieve and make a temp record that is a combination of default values and overridden values.

Comment: these examples are strange since I don't see any column named `itemxa_intid` in your example data but all of your queries reference it.  IT IS IMPOSSIBLE TO UNDERSTAND WHAT YOU ARE DOING IF YOU LEAVE OUT COLUMNS THAT YOU REFERENCE

Comment: Sorry, that was not intentional. I accidentally had two columns with same name. I have fixed the bad one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Stuff function.

```
SELECT 
   SS.SEC_NAME, 
   (SELECT '; ' + US.USR_NAME 
    FROM USRS US
    WHERE US.SEC_ID = SS.SEC_ID
    FOR XML PATH('')) [SECTORS/USERS]
FROM SALES_SECTORS SS
GROUP BY SS.SEC_ID, SS.SEC_NAME
ORDER BY 1
```

[image]

Comment: This will work, but don't you think STRING_AGG is a better approach? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: That's another way to skin this cat!

Comment: @ASN -- We could also write it on index cards and hire people on fiver to do it -- but no one would (or should) skin a cat that way.  Don't you think it is worth it to try and show the best solution not just a solution?